# sql join on two fields in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

i have bookings table which has two people- i want to return person_1 as a row, person_2 as a new row but with the person's id related to the people table

This is as far as i got-but doesnt pull in booking info

```
 SELECT people.* FROM (
    (select booking.person_1 as id from booking)
    union ALL
    (select booking.person_2 as id from booking)
) as peopleids
join people on people.id = peopleids.id;
```

heres my structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `booking` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `slot` enum('morning_drive','afternoon_loop','return_drive') NOT NULL,
  `type` enum('911','vintage_911') NOT NULL,
  `car` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `person_1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `person_2` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dated` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `people` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `organisation` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `event_date` date NOT NULL,
  `wave` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

any ideas on how i could get a result set like- person.first_name, person.last_name, person.organisation, booking.dated, person.car, person.slot. im struggling with having two fields and having them to relate them into the one list

**update for anyone interested in this and joining a 3rd table**

heres my final query with php vars to pull in my certain dates and slots and also join a third table

```
    SELECT peopleids.id, 
       peopleids.car, 
       cars.nr, 
       p.first_name, 
       p.last_name, 
       p.organisation, 
       p.event_date, 
       p.wave 
FROM (SELECT booking.car, booking.person_1 as id FROM booking WHERE booking.dated = '".$date."' AND booking.`slot` =  '".$slot."' 
        union ALL SELECT booking.car, booking.person_2 as id FROM booking  WHERE booking.dated = '".$date."' AND booking.`slot` = '".$slot."' 
     ) as peopleids
LEFT JOIN people p ON p.id = peopleids.id  LEFT JOIN cars on cars.id = peopleids.car;
```

Comment: join people on people.id = peopleids.id ?

Comment: this works.. but doesnt allow me to pull the related booking info, whats the best way?

Comment: you need to select the rest of the fields in both your unions (select booking.person1, booking.someotherfield, booking.bookingdate)

Comment: @Chris Mccabe  : try out my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT 
       ag.id, 
       p.first_name, 
       p.last_name, 
       p.organisation, 
       p.event_date, 
       p.wave
 FROM (
      SELECT booking.person_1 as id, booking.Car as car FROM booking
      union ALL
      SELECT booking.person_2 as id, booking.Car as car FROM booking
     ) as ag
JOIN people p ON people.id = ag.id;
INNER | LEFT JOIN Cars c ON c.ID = ag.car
```

Comment: i need booking.car to be returned... and join to the cars table ( i know i never mentioned it in my question but i thought it would be easy to add my own join in but im stuck)

Comment: I do not know how both tables are related and what exactly you want to return, I've updated my query perhaps it give you some pointers how to achieve what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
    select people.first_name as firstname,
            people.last_name as lastname,
            people.organisation,
            booking.dated,
            booking.car,
            booking.slot from booking
left join people on booking.person_1 = people.id
```

OR

```
select people.first_name as firstname,
            people.last_name as lastname,
            people.organisation,
            booking.dated,
            booking.car,
            booking.slot
 from booking
left join people on booking.person_1 = people.id or booking.person_2 = people.id
```

check that...if you still need help will help you